# CSS image hover issue

Tags: css, hover

On the homepage of my website I inserted a new video and had the image of the video with an hover but that seemed to collide with the logo on the top left (it shifts to the right).

http://pt.drpedrocoelho.com/

Is there a way to make it not float back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in your css a property for `img:hover` that makes it float right :)

You may cancel that for your h1

```
h1.logo img:hover{float:left;margin:0}
```

Comment: Check the answer on the left so :-)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me audre. I wish I could rep people's posts up but i need 15 reputation first. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose i need to add that css code to the twitter and facebook buttons on the navigation bar as well? : http://pt.drpedrocoelho.com/

Comment: @JoãoPaulo yep it seems to be the same problem. But maybe the property img:hover{float:right} that causes problem is not useful and you may simply erase it. What it is use for ?

Comment: I removed the img:hover {float:right} property (left the rest), I initially added that so that the picture on the homepage (the girl and the boy) would float to the right, but they seem to be floated to the right without that anyway. But the Facebook and Tswitter icons are still shifting. Hmm. What could this be?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo `img:hover` act when the mouse is hover the image. so i think you can erase all of that property if you don't want image to be changed when its hovered. In that `img:hover` you have also a margin that makes your images moving.

Comment: Oh I see. I removed the margin:0; from the img:hover and it stopped the text going to the boy and girl image. The Facebook and Twitter icons are still being shrunk when you hover over them, but it's not the end of the world.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo strange, when i delete all of the `img:hover`, facebook and twitter links images are not moving anymore

Comment: thank you for being insistent. I removed   `width:auto;` from `img:hover` (I left the opacity in the img:hover so it works with the boy and girl effect). That did the trick. Thanks =)

Comment: I still can't vote up for lack of 15 reputation. But thank you audre.

Answer (score 0):

Also This Is Wrong

```
img:hover
{
margin: 0 0 10px 20px;
}
```

It Make Error In Hovering On Facebook Image

Make It

```
margin:0;
```

Comment: I added margin 0 and it seems to make it better, but the FB and Twitter icons are a bit smaller. And notice one other thing: if you hover over the image of the boy and the girl the text seems to be attracted to it lol :)

Comment: This CSS is a bit of a mess isn't it? :)

Comment: Yeah :) I Can Improve It If You Want